# write() argument must be str, not list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a register program using python 3.6.2 and i'm getting the following error: `write() argument must be str, not list`

Here is the code:

```
database = open('database.csv', 'a')
linetowrite = ['username', 'password', 'forename', 'surname', 'dob', 'artist', 'genre']
database.write(linetowrite)
database.close()
```

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `write` with a list, the error message is pretty straightforward. To make this work simply (but not necessarily correctly), you could convert the list to a string like so:

```
database = open('database.csv', 'a')
linetowrite = ['username', 'password', 'forename', 'surname', 'dob', 'artist', 'genre']
database.write(",".join(linetowrite))
database.close()
```

Better would be to use a proper CSV library, e.g.: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html . Otherwise you're likely to end up with escaping errors (what if one of your fields contains a comma?).

Comment: Thanks, fixed that.

Comment: Thank you it now adds it to the csv file however when a new account is created instead of adding a new row into the csv file it adds in on to the last cell. I also remove the quotation marks so it uses the information entered by the user.